# Typescript subclass inherited method allow undefined keys in argument

Tags: typescript, generics, inheritance

I have noticed a really weird behavior trying to have a subclass with generics parameters.

```
// no error for this code
abstract class BaseClass<Input extends object, Output extends object> {
  public abstract execute(input: Input): Output | void
}

class ChildClass extends BaseClass<{ content: string }, {}> {
  public execute(input: {content: string }){
    return true;
  }
}
```

There's no compile error for this code. However, I can make content not mandatory and typescript will be happy as well

```
class ChildClass extends BaseClass<{ content?: string }, {}> {
  public execute(input: {content: string }){
    return true;
  }
}
```

I don't know if this behavior is normal or not.

Where it gets really weird is that if I add a random key to the base class, the type checking then works as I would expect:

```
abstract class BaseClass<Input extends object, Output extends object> {
  // Adding any mandatory key here will do but not an empty object
  public abstract execute(input: Input & { __trustMeImNecessary: true }): Output | void
}

class ChildClass extends BaseClass<{ content?: string }, {}> {
  public execute(input: {content: string }){
    return true;
  }
}
```

Now I get
`Type '{ content?: string | undefined; } & { __trustMeImNecessary: undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ content: string; }'.` and if I make `content` mandatory it will work fine.

Is this behavior normal ? Can I actually use this hack if so ?

[Reproduction in the typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgYVXQB4BJAOwAcBXRHADwhzIBMMB7EAKx3gBoEA8jWq0GTVgg7d4APgQBvAFAIE1EMgCWsBKEgx4Cejxo4AFBso0AXAnIiEAMgUIA+i+hVIAWRwkAtgByPDjowFAAnjZULDgAZhY4zAgAvgCUNkIQ9gA+CABubBrMismKiihoGHgAFhrIzASVhmIsGNhg+IRgRPJIbGSMAwD8NnoWAOYp-PLJckoqapraRrAm5pYQNvKw-YObCGNkk2nzKghQOBBUUGQIHjgA3MopJWUV6Ag1dQ1dAEzNgwk7U6lR6fQGTH2h2O01mCmeiy0zWMjHWIi2OwhA1G0AmKVSpxUFyuNzuUCoj2epVKQA)

Comment: Method parameters are always checked [bivariantly](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance) which allows the unsafe thing you're seeing.  (`--strictFunctionTypes` only closes this hole for non-method functions).  As for the hack, I guess you *can* use it, since it's hard to get a type narrower than `I & {_x:0}` accidentally, but I'd be concerned about edge cases.  If you can refactor to instance properties instead of methods like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wvynnm) you will get stricter behavior.

Comment: Does the previous comment fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Oh I get it: when I add the extra parameter then neither the source is assignable to the target nor the target is assignable to the source ? If so you can go for that answer, you helped me plenty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance and Bivariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218) for relevant definitions.

TypeScript checks [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Method) parameters [*bivariantly*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance).  That means it accepts both *safe* subclass methods that *widen* the types of their parameters (*contravariantly*) and *unsafe* subclass methods that *narrow* the types of their parameters (*covariantly*).  This latter behavior is somewhat useful, but you're not happy with it.

---

If you have [the `--strictFunctionTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types) enabled then non-method functions are checked the safe way (contravariant in their parameters).  But there's no way to force the strict checking for methods.  You can change methods to function-valued instance properties and get the desired strictness:

```
abstract class BaseClass<I extends object, O extends object> {
  abstract execute: (input: I) => O | void
}

class ChildClass extends BaseClass<{ content?: string }, {}> {
  execute = (input: { content: string }) => true // error
}

class ChildClass2 extends BaseClass<{ content: string }, {}> {
  execute = (input: { content: unknown }) => true // okay
}
```

---

There's currently no non-hacky way to use methods here.  One might think of declaring the superclass method as a function-valued property and just override it with methods, but this is disallowed.  There's a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#51261](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51261) to specifically allow `abstract` function-valued properties to be overridden with methods, but for now it's not part of the language.

Your hack works by making the superclass parameter a [branded](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal) subtype of the original parameter type `I`.  Subclasses can easily do the safe thing, because any supertype of `I` is a supertype of `I & {__brand: true}`.  But it's now more difficult to do the unsafe thing, since now you'd have to find a *subtype* of `I` which is either a supertype or subtype of `I & {__brand: true}`.  Most of the ways to do that involve the implementing method use the branded key (`__brand` here, `__trustMeImNecessary` in your example code), which we're assuming is unlikely.  There might be some edge cases, but to first order this makes it behave as expected.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkqJLAsgGICuw8ALgJYD2wAaplRACYAKATkxh58hIkhAAjKHT4I6SeBhBQoSAELKIAYSUqAPAEkkEAB50IwLqqYSAVhHoAaJAHljZi1aQ379AHzCYmKS0rL07g5U5gBcSAAUDMAwUbEGAJRIALwBbgA+SABuTAxcokQAviJBisqqWgAWDBhcOrXu5paqGlDaulB6uAosHXQA-LGhiQDmSOXOuOUBBEFEppHmWfGJyXSxg-DDFrtIk8Az5RnZSDKcSAD0d8Z8Anxls1ViNSpIDU0tfQAmdqeLqaVr6faHYDHU7neaLQIrNbwKLITJbJIpPBDaFHWI0ADWwCYAHdgLNLgEbsgHt4CSAAJ5vSqiFmiEjQOCIJAACQQBMRRBCMjkCj66jBfUMmPkpg6Xh8DjozhcUR2wM63jsSqWbyFUhF4WRqISMtSMqQADJsQB9G03aQAWQgBjAADkHNAoCA+Az8ZYIAAzRLcCmxVV0dX5IolZkfIhfOqNZrg1RykESnqpgY4kbjE4yaazeG6lYRFHmU07Pa5vEFvhFi6ClZ8CB0Kh8cnUgDceveQRZ1XFvxTgI1Xm6vVqOYOuOhE0LZ2LeARyyRJnWECrWMhc5hi-OGTXZdb7c71z4nF7ZcqA4+lXKQA)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Great post as well